# rails where query for current date on DateTime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have created a model called:

`DoctorAppointment`, which has mainly two attributes, `apt_from: DateTime` object and `apt_to: DateTime` object

I have created multiples appointments for different times for the same day. And I am trying get all the appointment records for `apt_from:` having today's date. and for the whole week

This doesnt seem to work.

```
DoctorAppointment.where("apt_from =?" ,DateTime.now)
```

This doesnt seem to return any records, even though I created some records on the current date.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I fixed one of the issues I was facing, because of the sql keyword conflict. After seeing the comment.

I am using Rails 6 and sqlite

Comment: Not a ruby expert but 'from' looks like a SQL keyword to me

Comment: @TobiSH Seems like it is I fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DoctorAppointment.where("apt_from > ? AND apt_from < ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day)
```

This will return all the records for today

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `DateTime` with `DateTime` which are different hence you are not getting any results. To find Today's appointment you just need to check the `Date` & not `DateTime`

Try [strftime](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function of sqlite

To find Today's appointment

```
DoctorAppointment.where("STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', apt_from) = ?", Date.today)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when comparing dates between SQL and Ruby, because of time zones. I find it is safer to use `Time.current` because that method is timezone-aware.

You could do this... `all_day` is a special Rails method which returns the range

```
Time.current
-> Wed, 09 Sep 2020 00:00:00 UTC +00:00..Wed, 09 Sep 2020 23:59:59 UTC +00:00


DoctorAppointment.where(apt_from: Time.current.all_day)
```